# Replacement for hyperref

Tags: hyperref

Is there other packages in LaTeX like `hyperref` that implement clicable links in pdfs? I mean, a package that does the same job but implement things in a different way and can be used as a general purpose package.

Comment: What is your definition of "general purpose" because according to my definition `hyperref` is as `general purpose` as it can get. What is it exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the reasons to *not* use `hyperref`?

Comment: There is also the `navigator` package, which works across engines and with TeX, LaTeX, and ConTeXt. If you use TeX Live, try `texdoc navigator`.

Comment: This is more a general purpose question. I am not against `hyperref`, and for me it is a must load package. However, in LaTeX we often have many alternatives and I was wondering if there is such alternative for `hyperref`. I will check navigator.

Comment: Without more detail on what 'general purpose' means here, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: As a general purpose I mean a package with a different implementation than `hyperref` that does the same job as `hyperref` does: have hyperlinks, and can be used with the various types of document classes that are available in LaTeX: presentations, papers, books, reports, etc.

Comment: @Daniel The reasoning is obvious: there're other packages that are incompatible with hyperref yet are crucial for the document (or marked as compulsory by the used style file).